# Cambiar separador de decimales en precio - ANDROID

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Soy nuevo en desarrollo en android studio y quisiera mostrar los datos de saldo (moneda) con el separador punto (.) y no como me muestra actualmente con coma (,). Actualmente la caja de texto recibe los datos de está variable que se encuentra en el string.xml.

```
<string name="drawer_header_balance">Saldo disponible:S/. %.2f </string>
```

- Se muestra: " Saldo disponible: S/. **`15,27`** "
- Deseo que sea así: " Saldo disponible: S/. **`15.27`** "

Comment: Hola @RobinsonAscencioPena agrega por favor como lo estas cargando!

Answer (score 0):

Una idea es convertir tu variable `float` a `String` y utilizar el método `replace`, de esta forma:

```
/*NUMERO FLOAT*/    
float numero=(float) 15.27;

/* NUMERO FLOAT CON DOS DECIMALES CONVERTIDO A STRING*/      
String numero_con_dos_decimales=String.format("%.2f", numero);

/*ELIMINANDO LA COMA Y REEMPLAZANDO POR EL PUNTO */                    
String float_con_punto= numero_con_dos_decimales.replace(',', '.');
```

Luego pasas la variable `float_con_punto` de tipo string a que se muestre en:

```
<string name="drawer_header_balance">Saldo disponible:S/.  </string>
```

Eliminando el: `%.2f` por que ya no lo necesitarias

Comment: Consulta: Y no hay una forma sencilla que desde la configuraión del proyecto se cambie la configuración del separador?

Answer (score -1):

Esta es una solución, cambia el valor dentro de strings.xml :

```
<string name="drawer_header_balance">Saldo disponible:S/. %s </string>
```

ahora convierte el valor tipo double que obtienes y aplica el formato:

```
    Double valor = 15.27;

    //Convierte a String y reemplaza , por .
    String valorString = String.valueOf(valor).replace("," ".");

    //Obtiene valor de Strings.xml y aplica formato
    String resultado = String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.drawer_header_balance), valorString );
```

De esta forma obtendrías:

```
 Saldo disponible:S/. 15.27
```

Comment: **¿ Algún comentario por el -1 ?, Cual es el error**

Comment: Consulta: Y no hay una forma sencilla que desde la configuraión del proyecto se cambie la configuración del separador?

Comment: Agrega por favor como estas cargando el recurso desde strings.xml  y como le asignas el formato.

Comment: Lo está cargando así: android:text='@{@string/service_card_cost(item.cost)}'

Comment: Aún no logro descubrir como lo obtiene, este caso del los decimales está en varios campos del proyecto que tengo y estoy estudiando.

Comment: agrega en tu pregunta de que forma cargas drawer_header_balance